# Finding the maximum overall probability of Alice's winning

Tags: probability

> Alice gives Bob two choices. If Bob chooses option 1, Alice's winning probability is $\dfrac{(a + b)^2}{2(a^2 + b^2)}$, and for choice 2 is $\dfrac{(a + c)^2}{2(a^2 + c^2)}$. Find the maximum overall probability of Alice's winning.

A note here, $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 1$. It is my understanding that the maximum overall probability of Alice's winning, whatever Bob chooses, is half the sum of these two quantities. Am I right? Because Bob can choose either choice with 50% probability.

However, in the [reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0609034v2.pdf)(page 3) that I am following, the author said that Alice's overall maximum winning probability is given by
$$\frac{1}{4}(2a^2 + 2ab + 2ac + b^2 + c^2).$$
I am not seeing how this is the correct expression. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that you need to understand the context a bit better. The paper says

> If Bob gets outcome 1, then Alice cannot win. On the other hand, if
>   Bob gets outcome 0, the state of the remaining system becomes .... and
>   Alice can win if she can pass Bob’s test in the final step of the
>   protocol. .... Alice therefore cannot fool Bob into thinking she was
>   honest with probability greater than .....

That last probability ($\frac{(a+b)^2}{2(a^2+b^2)}$) is the conditional probability, given that Bob got 0, Alice can win. What you want is the overall probability. I imagine (without having calculated it) that for this term, that is
$$
\frac{(a+b)^2}{4},
$$
and you'll get similar for the other term,
$$
\frac{(a+c)^2}{4},
$$
and adding the two together will give you want you want.